# is there a more efficient way to convert string to dictionary than using two for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simpler way of doing the following code:

```
# Import data for CSV

csv_file = open("csv_file.txt", "r")
list_csv = [x.strip() for x in csv_file.readlines()]


#   Convert to dictionary
list_item = []
dictionary_item = []

for item in list_csv:
    item = item.split(",")
    list_item.append(item)

for x in list_item:
    dictionary_item.append({'club': x[0],
                            'city': x[1],
                            'country': x[2]})

print(dictionary_item)
```

Contents of "csv_file.txt" :

```
Manchester United, Manchester,UK
Real Madrid,Madrid,Spain
Juventus,Turin,Italy
```

Explanation of what I am trying to achieve:

I want to get the data from the CSV file then convert it into a list which contains a dictionary with keys as "club", "city", "country" and the values are the ones in the CSV File.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Just have a single loop which dispenses with the two intermediate lists (`list_csv` and `list_item`). You don't need them.

Comment: I didn't get your point..

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: There is no point to build up a list from an iterable only to turn around and iterate over that list. The file is already iterable. You don't need to gather the lines into a list as an intermediate step. Also: it is cleaner to use `with` rather than just `open` when processing a text file.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `csv.DictReader` (which would do all the work for you)?

Comment: @ProgrammingDude Yeah.

Comment: @John Coleman Okay.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I wasn't aware of it as I am new to it.

Comment: @Utkarsh: K, just making sure this wasn't some misguided school assignment. Then the correct answer is "Use `csv.DictReader`." :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger no no it’s not a school project. I was trying to apply logic and solve the problem but turns out I do a lot of complicated stuffs but do get the solution. That’s why I was looking for a better solution. Thanks for the help :))

Comment: @ShadowRanger As a school assignment it wouldn't be that misguided. Reinventing some wheels isn't a bad idea when you are first learning how wheels work.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Reinventing CSV parsing specifically is bad. It's not standardized, and has so many pitfalls to implement a parser for even a single dialect that a lesson that teaches it for any purpose other than "This is why you use existing parsers" is just going to teach bad habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) reading functionality:

```
import csv

with open('csv_file.txt', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, ('club', 'city', 'country'))
    clubs = list(reader)
    
print(clubs)
# [{'club': 'Manchester United', 'city': ' Manchester', 'country': 'UK'}, {'club': 'Real Madrid', 'city': 'Madrid', 'country': 'Spain'}, {'club': 'Juventus', 'city': 'Turin', 'country': 'Italy'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to have 2 for loops, as you can split the item and put it into the format you want in a single for loop like so:

```py
# Import data for CSV

csv_file = open("csv_file.txt", "r")
list_csv = [x.strip() for x in csv_file.readlines()]

dictionary_item = []

for item in list_csv:
    x = item.split(",")
    dictionary_item.append({'club': x[0],
                            'city': x[1],
                            'country': x[2]})

print(dictionary_item)
```

Python also has [a built in CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which it might be better practice to use if you don't want to do everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

When I first looked at your question I noticed that the for loops do almost the same thing. Here's how I was able to while keeping the output the same.

```
# Import data for CSV

csv_file = open("soccer_clubs.txt", "r")

dictionary_item = []

for x in csv_file.readlines():
    x.strip()
    dictionary_item.append({'club': x[0],
                            'city': x[1],
                            'country': x[2]})
    
print(dictionary_item)
```